# UIActivityIndicatorView is not working with io5

Tags: ios4, uiactivityindicatorview, ios5

I have UIActivityIndicatorView in my app while info is loading. So IN simulator ios 4.3 it is working fine but in ios5.0 i can't see it. What is wrong? If you need code let me know. Thank you

Comment: I think the default activityIndicatorViewStyle in iOS5 is white.  Do you have a white background?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)Viewdidload
{
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

        [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];

        [self.view addSubview:activity];


}  
-(void)PressLoginBtn
{
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[activity startAnimating];

// call another controller

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[activity stopAnimating];
}
```